# Estoy trabajando con NODE.JS, EXPRESS, Multer, react, Apis post get put delete como un breve resumen; Quiero probar mis apis en postman pero no da

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, multer

*No inserta al momento de mandar la solicitud me aparece en postman:
{
"error": "Error en la carga del archivo"
}
Coloque bien el postman para probar la Api en FormData y en campo de imagen en File pero no se que falla...
Mi proyecto es un crud completo para un sistema de informacion de iglesias (Proyecto universitario)
Nose que pueda estar fallando, la imagen que subo no supera los 200kb y en mi base de dato el campo de la imagen que este caso seria Iglesia_imagen es longblob
Procedo a adjuntar mi controlador con la respectiva configuracion del multer...*

```
const IglesiaModel = require('../models/Iglesia-model');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// Configuración de Multer para almacenar temporalmente las imágenes en disco
const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: path.join(__dirname, '../pictures'), // Carpeta de destino para las imágenes temporales
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-onechild-' + file.originalname); // Nombre único de cada imagen
  }
});

const fileUpload = multer({ storage: diskStorage }).single('image'); // Utilizar diskStorage 
const IglesiaController = {};

IglesiaController.getAll = (req, res) => {
  IglesiaModel.getAll((err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    }
  });
};

IglesiaController.getOne = (req, res) => {
  let cod_iglesia = req.params.id;

  IglesiaModel.getOne(cod_iglesia, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    } else if (rows.length === 0) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Iglesia no encontrada' });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(rows[0]);
    }
  });
};

IglesiaController.post = (req, res) => {
  try {
    fileUpload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Error en la carga del archivo' }); //Aca esta el error de postman
      } else if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
      }

      if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No se ha proporcionado ningún archivo de imagen' });
      }

      const tempImagePath = req.file.path;

      fs.readFile(tempImagePath, (readErr, data) => {
        if (readErr) {
          return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al leer el archivo temporal' });
        }

        let iglesia = {
          PC_operacion: 'I',
          PI_cod_iglesia: req.body.cod_iglesia,
          PV_nombre_iglesia: req.body.nombre_iglesia,
          PV_nombre_CDE: req.body.nombre_CDE,
          PI_cantidad_niños: req.body.cantidad_niños,
          PI_cod_telefono: req.body.cod_telefono,
          PI_cod_direccion: req.body.cod_direccion,
          PI_cod_pastor: req.body.cod_pastor,
          PB_iglesia_imagen: data
        };

        IglesiaModel.post(iglesia, (dbErr) => {
          if (dbErr) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: dbErr.message });
          } else {
            return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Iglesia registrada correctamente' });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error en el controlador de creación de iglesia:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor', details: error.message });
  }
};

IglesiaController.put = (req, res) => {
  try {
    fileUpload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Error en la carga del archivo' });
      } else if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
      }

      if (!req.file) {
        let iglesia = {
          PC_operacion: 'U',
          PI_cod_iglesia: req.body.cod_iglesia,
          PV_nombre_iglesia: req.body.nombre_iglesia,
          PV_nombre_CDE: req.body.nombre_CDE,
          PI_cantidad_niños: req.body.cantidad_niños,
          PI_cod_telefono: req.body.cod_telefono,
          PI_cod_direccion: req.body.cod_direccion,
          PI_cod_pastor: req.body.cod_pastor
        };

        IglesiaModel.put(iglesia, (dbErr) => {
          if (dbErr) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: dbErr.message });
          } else {
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Iglesia actualizada correctamente' });
          }
        });
      } else {
        const tempImagePath = req.file.path;

        fs.readFile(tempImagePath, (readErr, data) => {
          if (readErr) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al leer el archivo temporal' });
          }

          let iglesia = {
            PC_operacion: 'U',
            PI_cod_iglesia: req.body.cod_iglesia,
            PV_nombre_iglesia: req.body.nombre_iglesia,
            PV_nombre_CDE: req.body.nombre_CDE,
            PI_cantidad_niños: req.body.cantidad_niños,
            PI_cod_telefono: req.body.cod_telefono,
            PI_cod_direccion: req.body.cod_direccion,
            PI_cod_pastor: req.body.cod_pastor,
            PB_iglesia_imagen: data
          };

          IglesiaModel.put(iglesia, (dbErr) => {
            if (dbErr) {
              return res.status(500).json({ error: dbErr.message });
            } else {
              return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Iglesia actualizada correctamente' });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error en el controlador de actualización de iglesia:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor', details: error.message });
  }
};

IglesiaController.delete = (req, res) => {
  let iglesia = {
    PC_operacion: 'D',
    PI_cod_iglesia: req.params.id,
  };

  IglesiaModel.delete(iglesia, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Iglesia eliminada de forma correcta' });
    }
  });
};

module.exports = IglesiaController;
```

Ahora el Modelo del controller...

```
const db = require('../config/database');

const IglesiaModel = {};

IglesiaModel.getAll = (cb) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM iglesias ORDER BY cod_iglesia', cb);
};

IglesiaModel.getOne = (cod_iglesia, cb) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM iglesias WHERE cod_iglesia = ?', [cod_iglesia], cb);
};

IglesiaModel.post = (data, cb) => {
  db.query(
    'CALL iglesia_InsertUpdateDelete(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
    [
      data.PC_operacion,
      data.PI_cod_iglesia,
      data.PV_nombre_iglesia,
      data.PV_nombre_CDE,
      data.PI_cantidad_niños,
      data.PI_cod_telefono,
      data.PI_cod_direccion,
      data.PI_cod_pastor,
      data.PB_iglesia_imagen
    ],
    cb
  );
};

IglesiaModel.put = (data, cb) => {
  let params = [
    data.PC_operacion,
    data.PI_cod_iglesia,
    data.PV_nombre_iglesia,
    data.PV_nombre_CDE,
    data.PI_cantidad_niños,
    data.PI_cod_telefono,
    data.PI_cod_direccion,
    data.PI_cod_pastor
  ];

  if (data.PB_iglesia_imagen) {
    params.push(data.PB_iglesia_imagen);
  } else {
    params.push(null); // Si no se proporciona una nueva imagen, pasamos null al procedimiento almacenado
  }

  db.query('CALL iglesia_InsertUpdateDelete(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', params, cb);
};

IglesiaModel.delete = (data, cb) => {
  db.query(
    'CALL iglesia_InsertUpdateDelete(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
    [data.PC_operacion, data.PI_cod_iglesia, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    cb
  );
};

module.exports = IglesiaModel;
```